# Compare or match values in an oracle table to data in an excel document

Tags: sql, oracle, excel, match, string-comparison

I have an Oracle database with a table called "Persons".  It holds the data you'd expect, such as Person_ID, name, address, phone number etc...

I also have an excel document with similar data.  I need to carry out some investigative work for a potential migration task in the future.  The excel doc does NOT have any unique ID style identifiers, just names/address/phone numbers.

I have the idea of trying to export the Oracle table as `.xls`/`.csv` and trying to compare it/ highlight matches it has with the excel document.  Is there a way of doing this?  I assume there is a way to export a table aswell?

Thanks!

Comment: What tools are you using? PLSQL Developer can export table data directly to Excel file, while SQL Developer can export it to simple .txt file.

Comment: I have the latest SQL developer, I think it has .csv export option.

Comment: I would rather consider importing Excel data into database as far as SQL and PL/SQL give you much more versatile tools for data compare and merge.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that.  Any idea the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this is to:

Start by creating a table in Oracle where you can insert the excel data into the database. You can use something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE excel_dump AS SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE 1 = 0;
```

Then in excel you can create a column to hold an insert statement - so if column `A` holds `Person_ID` values and column `B` holds name values then, for the first row, you can use:

```
="INSERT INTO excel_dump (Person_ID, name) VALUES ( "&A1&", '"&SUBSTITUTE(B1,"'", "''") &"' );"
```

Add more columns as appropriate (numeric fields can be concatenated without any issues, as per the `A1` cell, but text fields should be wrapped in `SUBSTITUTE( ?, "'", "''" )` so that any single quotes in the data are escaped, as per the `B1` cell). Then copy that for each row.

Copy and paste the insert statements generated from those rows into your favourite oracle client (SQL Developer / SQL*Plus / Toad etc) to populate the `excel_dump` table.

Then you can do whatever investigations you want comparing the two tables. So if you want to see the rows from the excel spreadsheet which do not match the rows in the `Persons` table then you can do something like:

```
SELECT Person_ID, Name FROM excel_dump
MINUS
SELECT Person_ID, Name FROM Persons;
```

Or some more complex analysis as you find appropriate.

**Alternately**

If you are using SQL Developer, then it has an option to [import data from an Excel spreadsheet](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12151_01/doc.150/e12152/dialogs.htm#sthref501).

Comment: Great, I;ll try this out.  Although the P_ID won't be an option though, as the excel doc has no unique identifier. Maybe I misunderstood your example?  I'll try the SQL developer option first and see how that goes. Thanks.

Comment: Just use what columns you do have/need - you can tailor the queries to work on some or all of the columns as appropriate so you don't need to worry if there is a column missing from the excel.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like a good fit for an [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) tool. I am personally fond of the Pentaho Data Integration utility available in their open-source [Community edition](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Data%20Integration/), but there are many options in the same market.